# Writing a JSON file and Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

Good afternoon, I found an example of a code with a parser that parses the site, takes from there the title of the article, a link to it and a short description, and writes this data to a JSON file. I redid it a bit for my site that I need, but of course everything does not work quite as it should. After writing, the "title" and "desc" data are recorded the same for all articles, but with "url" and "id" everything is fine and as it should be. Please help me solve the problem. I'll be very thankful.

Here is the code:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }

    url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/index.php?id=2&no_cache=1"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")

    news_dict = {}
    for article in articles_cards:
        article_title = article.find("h3").text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

        for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='more', href=True):
        
            article_url = (f'https://bmr.gov.ua/{i["href"]}')
        

            article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]
        

        # print(f"{article_title} | {article_url}")

            news_dict[article_id] = {

                "article_title": article_title,
                "article_url": article_url,
                "article_desc": article_desc

            }

        with open("news_dict.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And here is the result of writing to json:

[image]

Comment: Please accept an answer if it answers your question by clicking on the check mark next to it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite previous results because of the two nested for loops. You only need to iterate over the articles once and thus only need one loop:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }

    url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/index.php?id=2&no_cache=1"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")

    news_dict = {}
    for article in articles_cards:
        title_soup = article.find("h3")

        article_title = title_soup.text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

        article_url = title_soup.find_all("a", href=True)[0]["href"]
        article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]

        news_dict[article_id] = {
            "article_title": article_title,
            "article_url": article_url,
            "article_desc": article_desc,
        }

    with open("news_dict.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_first_news()
```

Answer (score 0):

You had done mistake `for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='more', href=True):` you should try to find `<a class="more">` inside `article` but you are searching it inside `soup`.

***Here's working code:***

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
}

url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/index.php?id=2&no_cache=1"
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")

news_dict = {}
for article in articles_cards:
    article_title = article.find("h3").text.strip()
    article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

    for i in article.find_all('a', class_='more', href=True):    
        article_url = (f'https://bmr.gov.ua/{i["href"]}')
        article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]
    
        news_dict[article_id] = {
            "article_title": article_title,
            "article_url": article_url,
            "article_desc": article_desc}

with open("news_dict.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

If this solves your problem don't forget to mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get the id of an article multiple times in a loop. There should only be one id for each article, thus making the inner loop unnecessary. (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68362898/5882233).)

Comment: I am telling OP that there is mistake in `soup` variable and Try not to change any of Op's code. So, Yeah! I agree with you that OP is using unnecessary for loop there. But I am just telling OP that there is variable mistake. And OP hasn't asked anything about what you are doing there!! OP is just asking answer about why I am getting this? How can I solve it? Has he asked "Am I using unnecessary for loop here or what"?

Answer (score 0):

Pass this argument "html.parser" to the BeautifulSoup constructor as well. Hope it will fix the issue.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }

    url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/index.php?id=2&no_cache=1"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")

    news_dict = {}
    for article in articles_cards:
        title_soup = article.find("h3")

        article_title = title_soup.text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

        article_url = title_soup.find_all("a", href=True)[0]["href"]
        article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]

        news_dict[article_id] = {
            "article_title": article_title,
            "article_url": article_url,
            "article_desc": article_desc,
        }

    with open("news_dict.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: The fact that the OP got a resulting json file (see screenshot) means that installing "lxml" is not their problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works. But I will also need to specify the domain name before the link, since this site gives me a link without a domain name Thank you for helping)